# Canceling form edition but not triggering form validators

Tags: jsf, validation

is it possible to cancel a form, redirecting to the previous page, and preventing the form validators to be triggered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,

You have to use `immediate` attribute of the `commandButton`.

[Quote](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/html/h_commandButton.html):

> The immediate attribute is a boolean flag indicating that component events should be sent to registered event listeners immediately rather than after the validation phase of the JSF request processing lifecycle. The immediate flag allows you bypass JSF validation for a particular component.